"We might play" vs "we might be playing"

In the past, when she came to visit me we might play games together

This sentence means that when came to visit me we sometimes played lets say board games.

In the past, when she came to visit me we might be playing games together

Is the meaning here the same but continuous infinitive emphasizes that the action of playing was ongoing and continuous?

Will you please stop adding random numbers to your titles, they make no sense whatsoever.

Sure. I will not do that again

Can you answer my question?

What is the difference in meaning between 1. "When I was a child, we may have played games"  2. "When I was a child we might play games" and 3. "when I was a child, we would play games”?

In the past, we might have played X.Y, or Z.

The one with present progressive conveys, “At the moments when she used to arrive to visit me, it would not be unusual for her to find us in the midst of a game.”

Can't it have the second meaning that would be  that after she came to me then we were playing? Look at this example " when she comes we will be playing games together" here both are possible either I will start after or before she comes.

You’re drawing a flawed analogy with the future use of will. Consider I’ll be leaving tomorrow. It is nearly identical in meaning to *I will leave tomorrow.” But you can’t just substitute would for will and expect everything to work for the past in the same way. In this case, I would leave tomorrow is either conditional or counter factual.   It used to be volitional, as in Would that she were here, which means I wish she were here.

Can " when she came we might be playing games" mean  that we started playing after her arrival?

“Jdjv djdjc ntc hdjcjxd”      Are you accessing to the Worldwide Web through a very noisy acoustic modem?

Sometimes I have issues with that


Is the meaning here the same?

No. The continuous form of the verb implies that the action of the verb, at the time referred to, has started but has not finished.
You can't be "playing games" together before she arrives.

This is similar to present simple and present continuous:
We play every day. [a general idea]
We're playing today. [what we are doing right now. Emphasis on the activity]
We're playing today. [can also be future if it is still morning; emphasis on the activity.]
*We might play today. [the general idea]
*We might be playing today. [emphasis on the the activity of playing or on its possibility if it is still morning]
The OP's sentence now reads well:

In the past, when she came to visit me we might have played games together.

It is not related to the title of the question, which is what I answered.
